# Where in code to for collision? In object class? Mainline code?

Tags: collision-detection, design-patterns, lua, love2d

Making a simple game in Love 2D framework where if I click on an object then it disappears.

Do I check to see if I've clicked the enemy inside a function in the enemy object? Or just in my main.lua? Currently I have this code in my main.lua:

```
function love.mousepressed(x, y, button)
   if button == "l" then
      for i,b in ipairs(bugs) do
         if b:isClicked(x, y) then
            table.remove(bugs, i)
         end
      end
   end
end
```

Is there a standard design pattern on where this code should belong?

Answer (score 1):

What I do is make each entity handle its own collisions in its update function.  This may or may not be practical depending on your project...But for me, it works and makes it easier to manage collisions when there's multiple instances of an object.